# Is it possible to add a component with an arbitrary impedance matrix to LTSPICE?

Tags: ltspice, transmission-line

I would like to use the following workflow:

- Simulate the S parameters of coupled transmission lines in an electromagnetics tool (Sonnet etc.). Convert to impedance matrix if necessary.
- Plug the results into a circuit simulator, preferably LTSPICE, because I already know how to use it (although any other simulator that can be invoked from the command line would be fine too).

Is this possible?

LTSPICE has transmission lines available through the GUI, but not coupled lines. I did find [some mention of how lossy lines are implemented](https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#Lossy_Transmission_Lines) on the Wiki, but still I am unsure of how to convert a numerically defined impedance matrix to an LTSPICE component.

Comment: Note sure if it helps, but just in case...the way I've done coupled lines in LTspice is by using lumped models.  [The Clayton R. Paul book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Introduction+to+Electromagnetic+Compatibility%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471755005) provides equations for getting the per unit RLC (and coupled C) for several common geometries.  The accompanying CD also includes [a PC program](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/14137) which makes a subcircuit that provides the exact solution using that data.  However, it runs really slow in my opinion so I opted for the lumped model.

Comment: I found this on the Sonnet homepage.  It says it can output to SPICE format directly.  Have you tried it?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgrGq.png

Answer (score 2):

[@Tim Williams](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/622929/95619) deleted his answer, but the choice is a valid one: use S-parameters, provided you don't forget that `.TRAN` doesn't play very nice with `Laplace` or `FREQ` functions. You may get lucky, or not, but one thing that really helps is to have some strong pole at high frequencies, ensuring a drop (for the internal FFT -- `.TRAN` only, `.AC` has no problems at all).

If you need a bi-directional black box then, by extracting the input current and output voltage it is possible to combine the two and make a circuit something like this:

[image: bidirectional Laplace]

It's a bogus example with a lowpass output and a highpass current, but it's just to show how to make a bidirectional Laplace. a `FREQ` table is just a Laplace, in disguise, but some report that it behaves slightly better than the continuous Laplace transfer function (*s* instead of table). At any rate, the high pole will only help. There are some additional tweaking parameters: `window, nfft, mtol` (see the help under *LTspice > Circuit elements > E. ...*). To this day I don't know exactly what `mtol` is meant to do, but it's there as a choice, feel free to experiment. As for the high pole in `E2`, if it causes hiccups in `.TRAN` then try adding `/(s/1meg+1)` (extra division by an additional pole at 1/(2π) MHz, creating a large bandwidth bandpass).

The other method is an RLC(G) approach, provided you can do it. This would be the best option because it will run blazingly fast in both `.AC` and `.TRAN`, no glitches, but the response will only be as good as the approximation. [This site](https://www.sintef.no/projectweb/vectorfitting/) may help with that.

Comment: Do you know if this MATLAB function does the same thing LTspice does internally?  https://www.mathworks.com/help/rf/ref/generatespice.html

Comment: @SteKulov I wish I could say, but I don't have Matlab. I tried their "try this example", it loaded, but then an error popped out about "Matlab couldn't...", so I saw nothing useful. I thought maybe there's a path problem so I tried again, but it coughs at both `~` and `$HOME`, otherwise nothing. When you say that LTspice does internally, are you talking about s2p conversion (which it doesn't do), or the way it treats the resulting file as a `FREQ` data (this last one I couldn't find out, as you saw)?

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't try it before, but I just did and it works for me. The answer is "no" (I meant the latter option). In case you're curious, here is [passive.s2p](https://pastebin.com/xPw06gvD) and [passive.ckt](https://pastebin.com/J3jSjLtP). Looks like it creates a complex subcircuit using passives and linear F / G sources. I compared it to the `FREQ` subcircuit created with `s2spice101.exe`. [`.AC` looks pretty identical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TZnG.png) (except at freqs beyond the table), but [`.TRAN` has some notable differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apwdq.png), as expected.

Comment: I might be missing some context in that deleted answer. I guess I don't understand your answer then. Is the suggestion to take the `s2p` file and manually create `FREQ` sources using that data...but the Laplace example is just a quick example of showing how to connect such sources together for bidirectionallity? If so, it sounds like `s2spice101.exe` is an easier choice since it does all that for you? Also, do you know if the link you posted regarding RLC(G) is a similar process to what [this paper lays out](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.498.6659&rep=rep1&type=pdf)?

Comment: @SteKulov I meant that if you only have V and/or I then you could use that contraption, otherwise, yes, the conversion should do it for you. Matlab's page now runs (doesn't complain) but I see no apparition of any extra `.ckt`. Looking through yours I see [this equivalent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6ZDP.png), which is quite similar to what I've shown, but it's not the one from the paper. It has the same purpose but keeps the I/O unbuffered (e.g. the Zxx are directly exposed) -- which is a better approach if you have Zxx instead of S or H, etc.

Comment: Also, the `.TRAN` might (might not) be improved if you extended the `FREQ` triplets to include a high frequency pole (some drop, preferably not abrupt/sharp). No need for 100 steps, a few, well placed, so that the last one is well below the rest. But, I have to say, Matlab does a nice job, and it's certainly preferable to `FREQ` or `Laplace`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  One last note is apparently the "rational fit" has to be "passive" for the MATLAB SPICE function to work.  There's another function that uses an algorithm that can enforce passivity by tweaking the fit.  Just mentioning cuz I think it's interesting stuff.  I'll shut-up now.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/rf/ug/passivity-test-visualize-and-enforce-passivity-of-ratioanlfir-output.html

Comment: @SteKulov Oh no, I appreciate the news. It looks like Matlab has some nice tools in there. But, looking at this last one, their criterion for "passivity" is any gain above 1, which is not necessarily "active". But it's also dependent on the rest of the response, too, so most likely they chose the safe path.